# Azure Functions + nodejs + vscode: launch config to debug multiple azure function funcs?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

In all the tutorials using http triggers, the .vscode launch file has this:

```
    {
      "name": "Attach to Javascript Functions",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    }
```

So now I've added a second function in the same function app. It uses a service bug trigger. I'd like to test it locally before deploying to azure. So now **how do I extend the launch configurations**? I can copy the block and change the name but how will the debugger know which func to kick off?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No modification required actually. The inspector(debugger) is not attached to any specific function, instead, it is enabled for the function node worker, which loads all functions we create.

When we debug we could see

```
Starting language worker process:node  --inspect=9229
"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\node\dist/src/nodejsWorker.js" --host ...
node process with Id=2276 started
Generating 2 job function(s)
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/0c8f2c9a-80cd-4ab6-914e-1c65d29f43c6
```

Comment: hrmm... OK I don't get that, possibly because my 2nd function is failing with "The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered" Just give me a moment to rectify that and confirm I can exercise the 2nd func locally - I'll come back and accept answer. Sorry for delay.

Comment: @yen In the VSCode terminal(the path should be your function project), input `func extensions install` to install the service bus trigger extension. Check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#register-extensions).

Comment: omg... that worked!!!! I see "2 functions loaded" now... :D Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Latest VSCode version 1.61.0 breakpoint unbound.

my config

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "smartStep": true,
      "port": 58167,
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"]
    }
}
```