# Azure Functions in VS Code multiple projects

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-code

So I have been given a solution with 4 C# azure function projects in it. I was wondering how can I configure debug settings for each function project.

I can only find a way to do 1 at a time and that requires making changes in the settings.json every time I want to test a different Function project.
[image]

Not to mention this doesn't help when I am trying to debug multiple Function Apps at once (trying to replicate Visual Studio Multiple startup projects).

Any advice other then go back to Visual Studio? haha

Comment: Hey,Mexicoder, I found a issue may help you better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718654/azure-functions-nodejs-vscode-launch-config-to-debug-multiple-azure-functio/54719617#54719617

Answer (score 3):

- **For your case**, what you need is [Add configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_add-a-new-configuration) in `launch.json` file rather than `settings.json`. You can change projectSubpath using settings.json to meet your need just like what you did.

**Here are the steps and references for Debug configuration:**

**1.** An alternative way to start multiple debug sessions is by using a compound launch configuration. You need to modify `launch.json` file with [compounds](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations) manually like this:
[image]

**2.** After confuguration, you can click the Debug button to debug your Function like in Visual Studio.
[image]